# how admob/adsense works in android app?

Tags: iphone, android

I am trying to understandard how adsense for mobile apps work. The website typically has alot of text to tell the topic of webpage to get relevant ads. But mobile apps (e.g. a game, or some utility app - clock, etc) typically do not have alot of content to get relavant ads.

Can you share your experience on how mobile apps can provide better context for ads? Should one have more text in the app?

Thank much.

Answer (score 0):

Admob lets you choose what ad categories you want to display in your apps, as well as specifying the age range. Having all ad categories enabled would increase your chance of an ad being available on the server. If you feel the need to only have ads of a specific category, you can do this. I have not, as my goal is to have a high probability of ad impressions.

Ad Mob also lets you enable Google Ad Sense. You can read about it [here](https://www.google.com/adsense/static/en_US/AfcOverview.html?gsessionid=0g0-C5Ny-HnVBaeOvYuvUA).

Comment: Thanks for link. But it is for the "site". For e.g I read on the article "We work hard to understand your content and deliver ads that are relevant to specific pages, automatically, no matter how many thousands of pages your site may have, or how specialized or broad your content." <br> how does adsense know what is content in the app? The app has no webpage (no HTML)!

Comment: Read about enabling ad sense on admob's website. It's the same basis, I'm assuming. Admob lets you categorize and describe your app, and Ad Sense must pick up on those keywords.

Comment: I will read again. But as I understand categorize or describe your ad is like providing static keywords. If my app content changes, do I have to update the keywords at the admob website? That would be a pain :( Any further infomation anyone can provide would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: My guess is that you would have to change your keywords. I don't see how Ad Sense could analyze your application and determine what its content is. Question, what are you doing that is dramatically changing the content of your app, but is still the same app?